# create-react-app run as sudo and unexpected token '{'

Tags: node.js, webpack, create-react-app, yarnpkg, sudo

I've created a React app using create-react-app and attempted to run it under port 80, but it required admin permissions so I ended up running:

> sudo yarn start

which threw an error:

```
me@mypc:<projectDirectory>$ sudo yarn start
yarn run v1.19.1
warning ../../../package.json: No license field
$ PORT=80 react-scripts start
<projectDirectory>/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/node_modules/p-limit/index.js:28
        } catch {}
                ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (<projectDirectory>/node_modules/terser-webpack-plugin/dist/index.js:24:38)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

And the function it complains about look like this:

```
    const run = async (fn, resolve, ...args) => {
            activeCount++;

            const result = (async () => fn(...args))();

            resolve(result);
            try {
                    await result;
            } catch {}

            next();
    };
```

Afaik it is possible to use try ... catch block without the exception argument, I've even tested it myself to make sure.

My node version is v14.17.0. Could it happen that that module is using some archaic one which does not support the syntax? Any ideas how to fix this or to run react app created with create-react-app at port 80 in some other way?

Comment: Empty catch was introduced fairly recently.

Comment: I've just updated to v16.2.0 and it didn't change anything.

Comment: Optional catch binding is supported in Node from v10 https://node.green/#ES2019-misc-optional-catch-binding, so that shouldn't be a problem in 14 or 16. Are you sure Yarn is installed against those versions? Try `yarn node --version`.

Comment: Yep, it's the same. Same error when attempting to run via sudo a fresh create-react-app project.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and got solved by upgrading the node version to 10.16.0. Earlier it was 8.10.0. I would suggest you upgrade the node, npm version